# Save and Update in jpa CRUD repository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have one data already saved in my databse based on my repository and service.i want to save another data with postman by changing only the player id.But it is not create a new entity data.it update the existing entity data.My question is how to update a data by my service when it finds a existing id.But when it finds a new id it will save a new data into databse.

This is my repo:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CricketPlayerRepository extends CrudRepository<CricketPlayer,String>  {
    Optional<CricketPlayer> findCricketPlayerByName(String name);


}
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
public class CricketPlayerService {

    private CricketPlayerRepository cricketPlayerRepository;


    public CricketPlayerService(CricketPlayerRepository cricketPlayerRepository) {
        super();
        this.cricketPlayerRepository = cricketPlayerRepository;
    }

    public CricketPlayerService() {
    }

    public Optional<CricketPlayer> getPlayerByName(String name){
        return cricketPlayerRepository.findCricketPlayerByName(name);
    }

    public CricketPlayer save(CricketPlayer cricketPlayer){
        Optional<CricketPlayer> id = cricketPlayerRepository.findById(cricketPlayer.getPlayerId());
        if (id.isPresent()){
            //code here
        }
//        if (entityManager.isNew(cricketPlayer)) {
//            em.persist(cricketPlayer);
//            return cricketPlayer;
//        } else {
//            return em.merge(cricketPlayer);
//        }
        return cricketPlayerRepository.save(cricketPlayer);
    }

    public Iterable<CricketPlayer> findAllPlayers() {
        return cricketPlayerRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<CricketPlayer> findPlayersById(String id) {
        return cricketPlayerRepository.findById(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a picture of some text...? Maybe you could post the text instead, if you think it would help.

Answer (score 1):

save and update operations in hibernate ( and other frameworks) are based on id value. if an id exists merge (update) entity and otherwise save new instance. So it cannot be done in this context.

Comment: what's the logic then?

Comment: @NirobRasseen Some Notes. 1.If your data exists in the database first fetch it and assign its value to other entity. 2.If your data does not exist in the database create new entity save and then assign its value to other entity. 3. Don't try to change the id column of some row in a table because the id column used to differentiate between different rows in the regular table. finally, if you insist to change its value you can use **JDBC** pure but it is not reasonable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1)If PlayerId is primary key id, then you would have called merge(entity). If PlayerId is present it will update else it will create new record.

2)If PlayrerId is not primary key id. Best practice is to avoid PlayerId as primary key.

In postman you should pass database table primary key id along with PlayerId. 
   Then you call merge(entity). It will take care of create or update based on primary key 
   id is null or not.

for example below if you have passed primary key id in request.

```
    Entity e = new Entity();
    if (entityFromRequest.getId() != null){ //this is the db id from request
        //get the entity from db and then change the state   
        e = entity from db by using id
    }
    e.setPlayerId = entityFromRequest.getPlayerId
    merge(e);  // it will create or update record
```

Comment: https://github.com/KamrulHasan-Seu/Research-Methodology/tree/master/Game_Backend                      this is my project.Anyone help me out?